# Convert custom format string to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, sql-server-2012

I'm receiving date values(*as string*) from one of the source system. It is always a 8 char long as shown below. I'm really not sure why they have kept in this format.

```
15/06-10
07/03-03
28/10-04
10/07-90
05/07-55
```

But for my application, I need to convert this into a proper date format(i.e. `DD-MON-YYYY`).

- First 2 characters represent `Date`
- Next 2 characters(after `/`) represent `Month`
- last 2 represent `year`

In oracle, I can use `to_date` to achieve this. Something like

```
select to_date('15/06-10','yy/mm-dd') from dual;
```

But in SQL Server, I couldn't find such function. Is there a way to achieve this? The closest I have got is

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(100) = '15/06-10';
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS('20'+SUBSTRING(@d,7,2),SUBSTRING(@d,4,2),SUBSTRING(@d,1,2))
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way. Also It is giving the results only when I hardcode `20` for the `year`. But i'm getting data from `1950`. So I cannot hardcode `19` or `20` Expected output for above sample is

```
+----------+-------------+
| 15/06-10 | 15-JUN-2010 |
+----------+-------------+
| 07/03-03 | 07-MAR-2003 |
+----------+-------------+
| 28/10-04 | 28-OCT-2004 |
+----------+-------------+  
| 10/07-90 | 10-JUL-1990 |
+----------+-------------+
| 05/07-55 | 05-JUL-1955 |
+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Y2K strikes again! No one should be using 2 digit years. Fixing your data during extract is the best solution - and using a proper format for dates is far better than this bizarre one. But surely your response is that such is not possible. So the short answer is - anything that works is "right way". Adapt Gordon's logic to use 2 digit years with the appropriate style string - which you can find in the documentation.

Comment: Looks very strange format. How will you know whether it is `19` or `20`?  Suppose if the data is `10/07-19`, then do you expect `10-JUL-2019` or `10-JUL-1919`? That is the reason you should always use 4 digit format.

Comment: I agree that this format is a big problem. We are taking action to correct it. But for now, I need to fix the current data and i'm getting only dates from 1950. so from `50` to `99` i want to `19` and `01` to `20` i want `20`. For this `10/07-19` , i need `10-JUL-2019` @ArunPalanisamy

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have a `to_date()` function.  But here is a simpler way to do the conversion you want:

```
select convert(date, replace('20' + str, '/', '-'))
from (values ('15/06-10'), ('07/03-03'), ('28/10-04')) v(str)
```

The expression in the `select` actually changes the format to YYYY-MM-DD, which is trivially converted to a date.  However, SQL Server `convert()`/`cast()` is relatively smart about recognizing dates in strings.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But this is giving me wrong output. For eg., `28/10-04` it is giving `2028-10-04` but i want `28-OCT-2004`. Also I cannot hardcode `20` in the code. Becoz it may be `19` also as i'm getting date from `1950` onwards. I have added sample for that. Sorry that I didn't convey this clearly before

Comment: @Avinash . . . This returns a `date`.  If you want a specific format, then you need to convert the date to a string.  For the record, the code in your question *also* returns a date.  You can use `format()` or `convert()` to create a string with a date in a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `datefromparts()` and string functions:

```
select datefromparts(
    '20' +  left(@d, 2), 
    substring(@d, 4, 2),
    right(@d, 2)
) as dt
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB. But I cannot hardcode `20`.  Becoz it may be 19 also as i'm getting date from 1950 onwards. Sorry that I didn't convey this clearly before